# How to pass multi method from a component to other component by React-navigater?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am facing this problem in React native.
How to pass multi methods from a component to other component by react-navigater.

Actually, I know Redux or Mobx is better way to solve this problem but I can't do that in some reason from my boss...

So, Please let me know this.

example code is this.

```
method1() {
  this.setState({ checked: true });
}    
method2() {
  this.setState({ marked: false });
}

navigation={this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', 
           { method1: this.method1.bind(this);},
           { method2: this.method2.bind(this);},
)}
```

I wanna do above one but I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing your data as a single second argument prop:

```
navigation={
   this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', 
       { method1: this.method1.bind(this),
         method2: this.method2.bind(this)}
       )}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping.
I can do that with your advice.
Thank you a lot.